# Rails: issuing POST and other http requests from the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, console

Might be a dumb question, but is there a way to issue http requests directly from the rails console? Those that are POST / GET / PUT / DELETE? Without doing all the routing first?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `app.get` and friends:

```
app.get app.auctions_path # 200
app.post app.auctions_path # 200
```

The `app` variable maps to a `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` so all its methods are available to you, including routes.

Comment: Yaay for `app.get` and friends!